# In SVG how do I reuse text elements positioned in a group like shapes in defs?

Tags: svg

I am trying to accomplish a precise layered effect for text in SVG. My current solution below just copies and pastes the group element with the text elements inside correcting the x and y coordinates for each. I saw from another solution def and reuse and transform for shapes.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 960 640" style="background-color:#def">
<g style="font-family: Arial Black; font-weight: bold;" fill="rgba(244, 164, 96, 0.45)">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="480" y="610" font-size="160px">&#9829;</text>
    <text x="95" y="265" font-size="160px">PASSION</text>
    <text x="395" y="345" font-size="80px">FOR</text>
    <text x="135" y="485" font-size="160px">PEOPLE</text>
</g>
<g style="font-family: Arial Black; font-weight: bold;" fill="#def">
    <text x="439" y="601" font-size="160px">&#9829;</text>
    <text x="99" y="261" font-size="160px">PASSION</text>
    <text x="399" y="341" font-size="80px">FOR</text>
    <text x="139" y="481" font-size="160px">PEOPLE</text>
</g>
<g style="font-family: Arial Black; font-weight: bold;" fill="orange">
    <text x="440" y="600" font-size="160px">&#9829;</text>
    <text x="100" y="260" font-size="160px">PASSION</text>
    <text x="400" y="340" font-size="80px">FOR</text>
    <text x="140" y="480" font-size="160px">PEOPLE</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the effect you want, define the shape within a **defs** section and then refer to it from a **use** element.

So the equivalent of your sample document is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
     width="100%" height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 960 640"
     style="background-color:#def">
<defs>
  <g id="passion" style="font-family: Arial Black; font-weight: bold;">
    <text x="440" y="600" font-size="160px">&#9829;</text>
    <text x="100" y="260" font-size="160px">PASSION</text>
    <text x="400" y="340" font-size="80px">FOR</text>
    <text x="140" y="480" font-size="160px">PEOPLE</text>
  </g>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#passion" transform="translate(-5,5)" fill="rgba(244, 164, 96, 0.45)" />
<use xlink:href="#passion" transform="translate(-1,1)" fill="#def" />
<use xlink:href="#passion" fill="orange" />
</svg>
```

Don't forget to define the xlink namespace in your root svg element. Otherwise you'll get an error.